# HTA to Script to Browse AD Security Group Name and get the LDAP path

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap, hta

I have a HTA script for group membership information retrieval. I just started to learning HTA and tried my best to modify to fit my requirement

My Scripts does the below:

I have a static OU Named OU=MyDepartment,DC=org,DC=dev,DC=lab,DC=net

And all the Required / targeted AD groups will be located in above OU called MyDepartment .

From HTA Script I can select required AD group Name.

When I executed the HTA file it will Update "adminDescription" attribute in Active Directory to something I have hard coded in the script, and it works. However, am looking to update based on text box value which user can enter a value.

In the script below lines are executing to update required AD attribute i.e., "adminDescription" to "Scientist021".

```vb
Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2 
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & lst_groupfilter.Value)
objGroup.Put "adminDescription", "Scientist021"
objGroup.SetInfo
```

Currently I have configured to update this value when click on Get Members Button (I even wanted to rename this to button name to "UpdateValues".

I stuck at this place, I wanted to put value as "Scientist021" or whatever in the text which User can type in a text box 
Can anyone guide me in this please.
Script can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByYC_SU1_5khSk1wS25hSHBKMlk).

[image: See this photo..if my English is poor]

```html
<Html>
<Head>
<Title>Set Group AdminDescription</Title>
<HTA:Application
    Caption = Yes
    Border = Thick
    ShowInTaskBar = Yes
    SingleInstance = Yes
    MaximizeButton = Yes
    MinimizeButton = Yes>
<script Language = VBScript>
Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2 
Sub Window_OnLoad
    intWidth = 800
    intHeight = 600

    Me.ResizeTo intWidth, intHeight
    Me.MoveTo ((Screen.Width / 2) - (intWidth / 2)),((Screen.Height / 2) - (intHeight / 2))

    lst_members.Style.Width = 500

    'Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://OU=MyDepartment,DC=org,DC=dev,DC=lab,DC=net")

    strBaseConnString = objRootDSE.Get("distinguishedName")

    Set objOULevel = GetObject("LDAP://" & strBaseConnString)

    EnumerateGroups strBaseConnString

    Show_Group_Selection
End Sub

Sub EnumerateGroups(strDNSDomain)
    Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
    Const adVarChar = 200
    Const MaxCharacters = 255

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

    objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
    objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 
    objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Name, distinguishedName FROM 'LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & "' WHERE objectClass='group'"

    Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

    Set objDataList = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
    objDataList.Fields.Append "name", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
    objDataList.Fields.Append "distinguishedName", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
    objDataList.Open

    While Not objRecordSet.EOF
        objDataList.AddNew
        objDataList("name") = objRecordSet.Fields("name").Value
        objDataList("distinguishedName") = objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
        objDataList.Update

        objRecordSet.MoveNext
    Wend

    objRecordSet.Close

    objDataList.Sort = "name"

    objDataList.MoveFirst

    While Not objDataList.EOF
        Set objActiveOption = Document.CreateElement("OPTION")
        objActiveOption.Text = objDataList.Fields("name").Value
        objActiveOption.Value = objDataList.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
        lst_GroupFilter.Add objActiveOption

        objDataList.MoveNext
    Wend

    objDataList.Close
  End Sub

  Sub Show_Group_Selection
      span_GroupFilter.InnerHTML = lst_GroupFilter.Value
  End Sub

  Sub Default_Buttons
      If Window.Event.KeyCode = 13 Then
          btn_run.Click
      End If
  End Sub

  Sub Exit_HTA
      Window.Close
  End Sub

Sub Get_Members
    'Const adVarChar = 200
    'Const MaxCharacters = 255
    Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2 

    Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & lst_groupfilter.Value)
    objGroup.Put "adminDescription", "Scientist021"
    objGroup.SetInfo

    'Clear_Members
    'Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & lst_groupfilter.Value)
    'Set objDataList = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
    'objDataList.Fields.Append "name", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
    'objDataList.Fields.Append "distinguishedName", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
    'objDataList.Open
    'For Each objObject In objGroup.Members
    '    objDataList.AddNew
    '    objDataList("name") = objObject.cn
    '    objDataList("distinguishedName") = objObject.distinguishedName
    '    objDataList.Update
    'Next
    'objDataList.Sort = "name"
    'If Not objDataList.BOF Then objDataList.MoveFirst
    'While Not objDataList.EOF
    '    Set objMember = Document.CreateElement("OPTION")
    '    objMember.Text = objDataList.Fields("name").Value
    '    objMember.Value = objDataList.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
    '    lst_members.Add objMember
    '    objDataList.MoveNext
    'Wend
    'objDataList.Close
  End Sub

  Sub ExporT_To_TXT
      If Mid(document.location, 6, 3) = "///" Then
          strHTAPath = Mid(Replace(Replace(document.location, "%20", " "), "/", "\"), 9)
      Else
          strHTAPath = Mid(Replace(Replace(document.location, "%20", " "), "/", "\"), 6)
      End If

      strFileName = Left(strHTAPath, InStrRev(strHTAPath, "\")) & lst_GroupFilter.Item(lst_GroupFilter.SelectedIndex).Text & ".txt"
      strFileName = InputBox("Enter file name to save as:", "Save As", strFileName)

      If strFileName <> "" Then
          Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
          Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFileName, True)

          objFile.WriteLine "Group Distinguished Name: " & lst_groupfilter.Value

          For Each objOption In lst_members
              objFile.WriteLine objOption.Text
          Next

          objFile.Close

          MsgBox "File saved."
      End If
End Sub
</script>

<body style="background-color:#B0C4DE;" onkeypress='vbs:Default_Buttons'>
<table height="90%" width= "90%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
            <h2>Set Group AdminDescription</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Group Filter:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select size='1' name='lst_GroupFilter'  onChange='vbs:Show_Group_Selection'>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
            <b>Group Selected:</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span id='span_GroupFilter'></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Members:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select size='8' name='lst_members'>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width= "90%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            <button name="btn_run" id="btn_run" accessKey="G" onclick="vbs:Get_Members"><u>G</u>et Members</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button name="btn_export" id="btn_export" accessKey="E" onclick="vbs:Export_To_TXT"><u>E</u>xport to TXT</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button name="btn_exit" id="btn_exit" accessKey="x" onclick="vbs:Exit_HTA">E<u>x</u>it</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add a text box (not a select dropdown).

```
<input type=text id="userInput">
```

Then put the value from this box in the description

```
objGroup.Put "adminDescription", userInput.value
```

You'll just want to make sure to do validation in the text in this box (not empty, not too long, etc).